# Deploy a spring boot application in jboss fuse

Tags: deployment, jboss, springboot

I have created a spring boot application consisting of a rest API. I want to deploy it in jboss fuse karaf so that i can call it from a remote angular application. Kindly help me how to configure this activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the official documentation which contains all the aspects of the model.

[1] https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_fuse/6.3/pdf/deploying_into_apache_karaf/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.3-Deploying_into_Apache_Karaf-en-US.pdf

Further, these tutorials would be helpful too: 
[2] http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-frameworks/jboss-fuse/deploying-bundles-to-jboss-fuse
[3] https://tomd.xyz/articles/jboss-fuse-deploy/

You might also like to read the best ways to ask questions on this forum.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask